# Multiple IF formula for Excel its only printing 3 argument out of six and does not apply other 3 argument

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of product names on Column A, I have March Product Price on Column B and April Product price in column C.
I want to find out

- If the product price from March to April increase then write (Increased)
- If the product price from March to April decreased then write (Decreased)
- If the product price from March to April stay the same then write (Price not changed)
- If the product price cell from March (Column B) is empty and also April price cell (Column C) is empty then write (Blank)
- If the product price cell from March (Column B) is empty but April price cell (Column C) has value then write (New Price)
- If the product price cell from March (Column B) has value but April price cell (Column C) is empty then write (Product Withdrawn)

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B4), ISBLANK(C4)), "Blank",IF(AND(ISBLANK(B4), NOT(ISBLANK(C4))), "New Price",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B4)), ISBLANK(C4)), "Product Withdrawn",IF(B4 < C4, "Increased",IF(B4 > C4, "Decreased",IF(B4 = C4, "Price not changed", ""))))))
```

I have tried writing the code but it only prints increased, decreased and price not changed but it does not print Blank, New Price and Product withdrawn. I want all six argument to print

```
"Blank",
"New Price",
"Product Withdrawn",
"Increased",
"Decreased",
"Price not changed"
```

If someone can help me to solve this please. Thanks in advance

Comment: ISBLANK will return FALSE if there is a formula in those cells that return `""`.  Try something like `B4=""` and so on.